# Firebase filtering users using a "friends list"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this little android application in which I integrated a ListView of users. Well, all of them. I try to filter that, by using a "Friend list" for every user. Something like this:

[image: Firebase Database]

So I have to take that list from my current user, search for every single friend in "users" child and get his info.
However, i can not find any way to do it, because I have used FirebaseListAdapter, which doesn't seem to help me in this new situation , or I just do not understand how FirebaseListAdapter works and how to manipulate it. 
My code for showing all users looks like this :

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<User>(getActivity(), User.class,
            R.layout.layout_user, API.getInstance().getDatabaseReference()
            .child(Constants.USERS_CHILD)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, User model, int position) {
            // hide he progress bar
               mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

                // setup the user view
                TextView nameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
                ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);

                nameTextView.setText(model.getName());

                if (!model.getPhotoUrl().isEmpty()) {
                    Glide.with(ContactFragment.this)
                            .load(model.getPhotoUrl())
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp)
                            .into(photoImageView);
                }

        }
    };
    usersListView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);
```

Any ideas how to make it work?